# Display wget transfer in a more compact way (while keeping the error detection functionality)

Tags: shell-script, wget

I know that wget have some options to display or not the progress bars.

I would like to display the wget transfer in a more short way, or.. a percent or something dynamic but not taking so much space like the classic wget output because i have to insert it into a script with already it's output.

My goal is to display to the user that the file is being downloaded, maybe even it's speed but not ruining too much the overall look of the script.

**Important:** My wget passages are inside an if then else script, so I have to retain the error detection functionality.

My script have a block that looks like:

```
if wget -O filename http://someurl then
    some_action
else
    some_other_action
fi
```

Can someone provide me some funny examples of customized progress data or bars with this refinements? Thank you ;)

Comment: If @meuh's answer works for you, i suggest submitting a wishlist bug-report to the `wget` developers asking for a simple percentage --progress type.  or submit the bug report to your distro's `wget` package maintainers and ask them to forward it upstream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the "dot" progress output style, which is something like this:

```
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  2%  496K 91s
```

then you can pipe this (which is on stderr) into `awk` or similar and just print the "2%" field shown in the last-2 column.

```
wget ... --progress=dot -q --show-progress 2>&1 |
awk 'NF>2 && $(NF-2) ~ /%/{printf "\r %s",$(NF-2)} END{print "\r    "}'
```

This shows you the changing percent value on one line, which is cleared at the end.

---

To preserve the return code of `wget` for an `if..else` you can ask bash to make pipelines return the error code of any command that failed (instead of just the rightmost command) by setting in the script:

```
set -o pipefail
```

Alternatively, you could put all of the `if..else..fi` code unchanged inside a block and pipe the stderr at the end into a single more informative awk such as suggested by cas in the comments:

```
( if wget ...
  fi
  if wget ...
  fi
  if wget ...
  fi
) 2>&1 | awk '
/^Saving to:/ { fn = gensub(/^Saving to: /,"",1) }
NF>2 && $(NF-2) ~ /%/ { printf "\r%s %s",fn,$(NF-2) }
END { gsub(/./," ",fn); print "\r    " fn }'
```

or to avoid missing important error messages on stderr, just redirect the stderr on each wget command to a 3rd file descriptor:

```
( if wget ... 2>&3
  then ... else ... fi
  if wget ... 2>&3
  then ... else ... fi
  if wget ... 2>&3
  then ... else ... fi
) 3>&1 | awk ...
```

Comment: +1.  Here's a version that prints the filename with the percentage: `wget ...  | awk '/^Saving to:/ {fn=gensub(/^Saving to: /,"",1)}; NF>2 && $(NF-2) ~ /%/{printf "\r%s %s",fn,$(NF-2)} END{gsub(/./," ",fn); print "\r     "fn}` (there should be 4 spaces after `\r`, not just 1)

Comment: While I am aware of the possibility of piping the output inside another command to a further refine I was wondering: Doesn't this break the capability of wget of returning the status? I have inside my code an if block like: `if wget .. then .. something .. else .. fi` and I fear that piping the command will break the "if block" functioning.

Comment: with bash there are methods to get that return code. eg `set -o pipefail` will make pipelines return the error code of any command that failed in it.

Comment: @meuh I see, added the requirement inside the question, can you edit the answer covering these more cases? I was thinking that with sed you can pratically completely rewrite the output but is something doable only if you keep the error detection working..

Comment: @user3450548 I updated my answer with some ideas.